# Getting color from a NSColorWell in CGColorCreateGenericRGB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscolor, nscolorwell

I am trying to set the background color of an `NSTextField` like this

```
myTF.layer.layer.backgroundColor = [myColorWell color]
```

But I am getting an error

What is the beat way to get the color from a `NSColorWell` and set it to my `NSTextField`'s `backgroundColor`?

I hope i have to conver the color i got from the `NSColorWell` and convert to either `CGColorCreateGenericRGB` or `CGColorRef`  so that i can set the background

Can anybody please guide me?

Comment: Got it's pretty easy

    myTF.layer.backgroundColor = [myColor CGColor];

Answer (score 2):

Got it's pretty easy

```
myTF.layer.backgroundColor = [myColor CGColor];
```